# Persisting objects in objects using spring-data

Tags: spring-data

For the first time i am trying to use spring-data.
Everything works fine when i'm using object that has simple objects.

Now i'm trying to add Location object to User class.
User creation works fine (i use **POST request to /users**).
But when i try to add location (using **PUT or PATCH to /users/1/locations**) then comes 201 CREATED status, but no location is added (checked with **GET /users/1/locations**).

Source code is very simple and is accesible under this [link](https://github.com/kenji89/GeoLocServer).

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried annotating your Location class with @Embeddable and your location variable inside the User class with @Embedded? You need to do this in order to force an object to be stored inside of another in the database.